# How to remove bulk actions from custom post type

Tags: plugins, post-meta

i am currently trying to remove the draft(action) from the custom post type dropdown menu.
I am sharing a screenshot it will help you to understand my question.
I have no idea how to achieve this, is there any hook or method.
Kindly help me out.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I don't see Draft in there? Draft is a post status. Do you want to disable the ability to make a post type draft entirely? Or just related to this dropdown?

Comment: @JacobPeattie i updated the question please check

Comment: Those aren't normal options. Is this from a plugin?

Comment: Well thank you. someone has touched the core. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RajneeshTiwari can you show a larger screenshot for context? Can you confirm this is a 3rd party modification or a mod of WP core files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code for this. You just need to change the "posttype" in the action name, for which you want to remove draft from the bulk action.

```
function remove_draft_from_bulk_actions( $actions ) {
    
    if( isset( $actions[ 'draft' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'draft' ] );
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-posttype', 'remove_draft_from_bulk_actions', 99 );
```

**Below is the screenshot for this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is for remove rank math bulks

```php
function remove_draft_from_bulk_actions( $actions ) {
    
    if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_robots_noindex' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_robots_noindex' ] );
    }
        if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_robots_nofollow' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_robots_nofollow' ] );
    }
        if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_robots_index' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_robots_index' ] );
    }
            if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_remove_canonical' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_remove_canonical' ] );
    }
            if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_redirect' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_redirect' ] );
    }
                if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_stop_redirect' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_stop_redirect' ] );
    }
                if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_schema_none' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_schema_none' ] );
    }
                    if( isset( $actions[ 'bulk-action-selector-top' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'bulk-action-selector-top' ] );
    }
                    if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_schema_default' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_schema_default' ] );
    }
                        if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_robots_follow' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_bulk_robots_follow' ] );
    }
                            if( isset( $actions[ 'rank_math_options' ] ) ) {
        unset( $actions[ 'rank_math_options' ] );
    }
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', 'remove_draft_from_bulk_actions', 99 );
```

Comment: I'm sure you could do that neater with a loop.